# sshd activation on ubuntu system

Tags: ssh, sshd

I want to connect my work Desktop computer remotely from home. I have read that ssh is used to connect to remote/server machine.

When I was reading I came to know that to connect to a remote computer(in my case my work computer), sshd should be enabled on it. How to check whether sshd is already enabled on my machine and if not how to enable it so that I can access it remotely from my home.

Hope to hear from you soon

Regards

Comment: @waltinator well, it seems a quite extreme comment to me. If their company's policy is not to allow it, it will not work --- access to port 22 (and all the others, by the way) will be blocked straight away. "Outgoing-only connection" is the easiest firewall configuration...

Comment: @Rmano,waltinator: Thanks for the comments and answers. I will check with the IT person here

Comment: @user3138373: please accept the answer if it was useful to you.  http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two conditions here:

1. you need to have `sshd` working on your machine.
2. your workplace management should allow the access to port 22 to your PC, and give you a fixed IP (or an equivalent forwarding).

Point #1 is easy. For a very basic `sshd` installation, simply

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

You should be able to test it from the same machine with

```
ssh 0
```

and you should have the normal login prompt for your user (answer "yes" when it asks to add the fingerprint of your local machine).

This is a very basic configuration tough; you should go to the [help page and adapt it to your use case](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring).

For point #2, you should contact your IT management.

When and if the firewall permits it, you can now reach your machine from home (or from whatever computer) with `ssh user@IP` (for example, `ssh rmano@1.2.3.4`). If you do not know your external IP, contact the IT management(1).

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) you really can check it online, but that is not useful at all if you do not have the relevant ports opened/forwarded.

Comment: Currently I am working at my work Desktop computer. What command should I use to check whether this work machine can be connected remotely from home?

Comment: @user3138373, you have to check it from outside your corporate network. So you need an outside account to check it from you workplace --- ssh to it and then try to ssh back to your machine.